# Rest template getForObject() mapping only camel case fields

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

Having a rest web service that returns the below xml response.

```
Person>
<ttId>1408</ttId>
<FirstName>RAJ</FirstName>
<NationalityValue>INDIAN</NationalityValue>
<Sex>Male</Sex>
</Person>
```

This is the dto

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


public class PersonInfoDto implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long ttId;    
    private String NationalityValue;
    private String Sex;
    private String FirstName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Using Spring Boot, When I try to consume using code it returns only one value(which is in camel case).  Do I need to add any **Naming strategy** to make it work ?

```
String uri = apiPath;       
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
PersonInfoDto personInfoDto = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, PersonInfoDto.class);
```

//Here the object will contain only one value

ttId = 1408

rest values are returns null.

Is there any dependency is required for this ?
This is pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>msa</groupId>
    <artifactId>MQA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MQA</name>
    <description>MQA project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <orika-core.version>1.4.6</orika-core.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/c3p0/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Orika -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>${orika-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@XmlElement`. Try this

```
public class PersonInfoDto implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long ttId;    
    @XmlElement(name = "NationalityValue")
    private String nationalityValue;
    @XmlElement(name = "Sex")
    private String sex;
    @XmlElement(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Another option is to write custom Http Message Converter. Have a look at this http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

Comment: XmlElement this option I had tried. DO we need to create custom converter for this ?

Comment: I believe it should work with @XmlElement. Make sure you write it correctly(uppercase in XmlElement and camelcase in field name).

Comment: @XmlElement(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;   - no luck. Any reason why only camel case is working ?

Comment: tra adding this at the top of the class `@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")`

Comment: Tried. no luck.

Comment: Is this anything related to message converters ?

Answer (score 0):

Removed the below entry from the pom.xml. It worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```