# jackson-data-format doesn't convert when using with restTemplate getforObject()

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-dataformat-xml

This question is related to [[Rest template getForObject() mapping only camel case fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675870/rest-template-getforobject-mapping-only-camel-case-fields][1])

Having a rest web service that returns the below xml response.

```
 <Person>
    <ttId>1408</ttId>
    <FirstName>RAJ</FirstName>
    <NationalityValue>INDIAN</NationalityValue>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    </Person>
```

This is the dto

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


public class PersonInfoDto implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long ttId;    
    private String NationalityValue;
    private String Sex;
    private String FirstName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Using Spring Boot, When I try to consume using code it returns only one value(which is in camel case).  Do I need to add any **Naming strategy** to make it work ?

```
 String uri = apiPath;      
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    PersonInfoDto personInfoDto = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, PersonInfoDto.class);
```

//Here the object will contain only one value

ttId = 1408

rest values are returns null.

This is pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>msa</groupId>
    <artifactId>MQA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MQA</name>
    <description>MQA project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <orika-core.version>1.4.6</orika-core.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/c3p0/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Orika -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>${orika-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

When I removed the below entry from  it worked.

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

But to map the RequestBody with XML data this dependency is required.

**How can I solve this, which converter does rest template is using ? Can I force rest template to use a particular converter. ?**

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try adding @XmlRootElement on the PersonInfoDto class. And try once in web browser giving the URI which you are passing.